# How to show active mark on RadioListTile?

Tags: flutter

How to show active mark on RadioListTile? I used `selected` and `activeColor` but it does not work.

```
RadioListTile(
  selected: true,
  activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, //
  title: Text(AppLocalizations.key(context, 'setDark')),
  value: ThemeMode.dark,
  groupValue: _themeMode,
  onChanged: (value) {},
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html)

"groupValue → T?

The currently selected value for this group of radio buttons.

This radio button is considered selected if its value matches the `groupValue`.
"

The one selected is the one whose group value matches the value.

Therefore your radio buttons should have as `groupValue` `Theme.Dark` or `Theme.Light` and update it on `onChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two `RadioListTile` for this and will contain the same `groupValue`. Based on `groupValue` it will decide active  `RadioListTile`.

When `value` match with `groupValue` it will show active mark status.

```dart
class _HomesState extends State<Homes> {
  ThemeMode _themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RadioListTile<ThemeMode>(
                selected: true,
                activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                title: Text(
                  'setDark',
                ),
                value: ThemeMode.dark,
                groupValue: _themeMode,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _themeMode = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile<ThemeMode>(
                selected: true,
                activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                title: Text(
                  'setLight',
                ),
                value: ThemeMode.light,
                groupValue: _themeMode,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _themeMode = value!;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```